# how to change video style

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working in react and have one question.
I am working on video and can't give to video css style.
But when I am using react inline styles it's working, but I want to do same thing in css, how can I do that?... here is my code

```
   let style = {
         width: "100%",
         height: "90vh",
         objectFit: "initial",
         zIndex: "-100"
       };
    <video style={style}  autoplay="true" loop="true" muted>
          <source src={Video}></source>
    </video>
```

but when I write on this way  it's not working

```
 <video className="video-option" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted>
      <source src={Video}></source>
 </video>
.video-option{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    object-fit: initial;
    z-index:  -100;
   }
```

please help me resolve this problem because I need also write media queries  for my className="video-option"

Comment: Hi, could you add a minimal workign (or breaking) example of your code? Maybe as a `code snippet` or on CodeSandbox.io?

Comment: Yes, please include a CodeSandbox to replicate the code. Did you check that your class is inside in file css and imported in the component that you are rendering the video?

Comment: Try going through what is explained here http://mrbool.com/how-to-style-the-html-5-video-element-with-javascript-and-css/27683

Comment: Interesting, I write same thing in sandbox and it's start working 
https://isc2g.csb.app/